# How to define an object in NodeJS schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I currently have a schema like this:

```
const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    message: String,
    name: String,
    creator: String,
    tags: [String], 
    selectedFile: String,
    likes: { type: [String], default: [] }, 
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date(),
    },
})
```

One of the problem that I anticipate is that as the number of users grow, searching the likes array will become inefficient. Is there a way to store the likes array instead as an Object (key would be userId and value could be true) so that finding someone in the Object would become more efficient.

I am also open to hearing any other ideas that you might have.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I want to suggest populate() for this. From that, you can manage a large no. of user information without a problem. You can create a new schema as likes and add the id of the likes document as an id with the populate. Check the below example.

```
const likeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   type: [String], 
   default: [] }, 
});
const Like = mongoose.model("Like", likeSchema);
```

Then create the postschema like below.

```
const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    message: String,
    name: String,
    creator: String,
    tags: [String], 
    selectedFile: String,
    likes: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
        ref: 'Like',
    }, 
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date(),
    },
})
const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
```

You can easily get all the data inside a likes document by populating when running a query like below.

```
const posts = await Post.findById({creator_id}).populate("likes");
//Below code will print the data of the first element of the type array of relevant likes document.
console.log(posts.likes.type[0]);
```

Check the [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate) and [population](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population) sections of the mongoose documentation to learn more.